# Syntax error when trying to pass in multiple parameters for a SELECT from Python to SQLite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm getting an error from the second half of the `SELECT` execution claiming it's about a `,`. Around `(K[0], K[1], K[2], K[3], K[4], K[5], K[6],))`

Instead of `(list) = (?,?,?)` I've tried `L0 = ?` AND `L1 =?` which gave a different error

```
    K = [Loc.L[0], Loc.L[1], Loc.L[2], Loc.L[3],
        Loc.L[4], Loc.L[5], Loc.L[6],]
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM LocationTable WHERE (L0,L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,L6) = (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", (K[0], K[1], K[2], K[3], K[4], K[5], K[6],))
    if c.fetchall() is not None:
        print('Error. Location already exists')
    else:
        c.execute('INSERT INTO LocationTable VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',
                      (None, K[0], K[1], K[2], K[3], K[4], K[5], K[6],))
       conn.commit()
```

it says

> sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error

Comment: What version of sqlite are you using? And what is this *different error*?

Comment: sqlite3. And it said there was a error near [0]

Comment: What version of *sqlite3*? -- that sounds more like a python error than a sqlite error. But you really need to include the exact text, not vague summaries.

Comment: 3.16.0 yeah it's something to do with the syntax of passing in the parameters. I can't find an example similar online

Comment: 3.16 is old but barely new enough to support row values. So much for that idea.